# How to fill a circle color by percentage value?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

In my application I have a requirement in such a way that I need to fill circle with red color with percentage values like 50%, 80% which I am getting from API like below image.

[image]

Currently I am using the below code to achieve this.

```
    let roundView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250, height: 250))
    roundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    roundView.layer.cornerRadius = roundView.frame.size.width / 2


    // bezier path
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint (x: roundView.frame.size.width / 2, y: roundView.frame.size.height / 2),
                                  radius: roundView.frame.size.width / 2,
                                  startAngle:CGFloat(M_PI_2),
                                  endAngle: CGFloat (M_PI * 2.0),
                                  clockwise: true)
    circlePath.move(to: roundView.center)
    // circle shape
    let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
    circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    circleShape.lineWidth = 1.5        
    // add sublayer
    roundView.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
    // add subview
    self.view.addSubview(roundView)*
```

it is showing like below

[image]

Can you please suggest me how to do this. Currently I am facing problem converting percentage to degrees.

Comment: you may use https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart

Comment: This is also a good control to do this: https://github.com/yasuoza/XYDoughnutChart

Comment: Raki and bisma Thanks for your quick response i don't want to use Third party libraries.

Comment: hint: Q: how many point do you see on the desired image? A: __3__, _centre, start, end;_ Q: how many points do you see in your code? A: __2__, _start, end;_ Q: how any points are missing from your implementation? A: __1__, _centre._

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not drawing the full path - an arc alone will not do it. You need to start the path at the centre, and draw the straight edges of the segment as well as the arc. Here it is in Playground - I have tried to keep as much as possible to your style, but have introduced the parameters `proportion` which is your percentage, and `startAngle` which is the orientation of the segment.

```
import UIKit
let roundView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250, height: 250))
roundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
roundView.layer.cornerRadius = roundView.frame.size.width / 2

// vary this to move the start of the arc
let startAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2  // This corresponds to 12 0'clock
// vary this to vary the size of the segment, in per cent
let proportion = CGFloat(80)
let centre = CGPoint (x: roundView.frame.size.width / 2, y: roundView.frame.size.height / 2)
let radius = roundView.frame.size.width / 2
let arc = CGFloat.pi * 2 * proportion / 100 // i.e. the proportion of a full circle

// Start a mutable path
let cPath = UIBezierPath()
// Move to the centre
cPath.move(to: centre)
// Draw a line to the circumference
cPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: centre.x + radius * cos(startAngle), y: centre.y + radius * sin(startAngle)))
// NOW draw the arc
cPath.addArc(withCenter: centre, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: arc + startAngle, clockwise: true)
// Line back to the centre, where we started (or the stroke doesn't work, though the fill does)
cPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: centre.x, y: centre.y))
// n.b. as @MartinR points out `cPath.close()` does the same!

// circle shape
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
circleShape.path = cPath.cgPath
circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
circleShape.lineWidth = 1.5
// add sublayer
roundView.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
roundView
```

[image]

**Bonus - add a text label**

The OP threw a couple of curved balls after my initial answer, including orienting the segment (implemented above) and labelling the segment with the percentage, which *really* should have been a separate question, however, it's not an unreasonable thing to want to do on a pie-chart, so here its is...

```
// Bonus - add text layer
// choose your font
let fontSize = CGFloat(20)
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
// Format the string
let str = String(format: "%3.0f%%", proportion)
// Calculate the text size
let textSize = str.size(attributes: attributes)

// Assume the centre of the text is half way along the bisector of the segment
let halfAngle = startAngle + arc / 2
let centreText = CGPoint(x: centre.x + radius * cos(halfAngle) / 2, y: centre.y + radius * sin(halfAngle) / 2)
// calculate the the lower left of the label given the size
let originText = CGPoint(x: centreText.x - textSize.width / 2, y: centreText.y - textSize.height / 2)
// Allocate the text layer
let label = CATextLayer()
label.font = font
label.fontSize = fontSize
label.frame = CGRect(origin: originText, size: textSize)
label.string = str
label.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
label.foregroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
roundView.layer.addSublayer(label)
roundView
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick and detailed answer. Two things i forgot to mention in my question. Q1) the circle should start from top like 12:00 clock and needs to fill green color clock wise. 2Q) I need to add lable on circle view which indicates percentage.

Comment: A line from the current point to  the initial point of the arc on the perimeter is automatically added by `addArc`. The second `addLine` can be omitted if you explicitly `close` the path.

Comment: @MartinR - indeed, but you need to either explicitly close it, or implicitly close it!

Comment: @MartinR - added your observation as a comment

Comment: Sure Thanks i will try it

Comment: @BeingLearner - have added the text label.

Comment: @Grimxn Thanks i have already added label but your answer really helped me a lot. This answer really need more upvotes