# filling a circle gradually from bottom to top swift2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Basically I'am very new to Swift 2 and have created a circle with a stroke and white background using below code, then I got a circle something like this:

[image: then I got a circle something like this:]

```
func getDynamicItemQty() -> UIImage {

    let View = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,200))

    let circlePath =
        UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100,y: 100), radius: CGFloat(90), startAngle: CGFloat(9.4), endAngle:CGFloat(0), clockwise: false)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath


    //shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10

    View.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    return UIImage.renderUIViewToImage(View)
}
```

However, how can we draw circles that is partly filled horizontally  in Swift 2? I mean circles which are filled, for example, from the bottom to the top according to the percentage specified in Swift code.

Here is a preview of what we need:

[image: desired output]

Comment: If you are new to Swift you should not be using Swift 2. It's long out-of-date. Learn Swift 4.

Comment: Your images are the same - did you mean for the first image to look different?

Comment: Here, I gave answer with Two Images, but, its from Top to bottom.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836938/uiprogressview-setting-to-an-image-uiprogressview-entire-contentview-downwards/48839378#48839378

Comment: @rmaddy sorry ,i edited 1st image

Comment: and i'am working on swift 2 project so cant just switched swift latest version right now

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087622/how-to-fill-a-circle-color-by-percentage-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view and a shape layer are definitely the wrang appraoch. You should take a look at [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623912-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwitho) or for iOS 10 or newer [`UIGraphicsImageRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer). For your problem: You should draw your circle twice. Something like that:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)
let circlePath =
    UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), radius: CGFloat(90), startAngle: CGFloat(9.4), endAngle:CGFloat(0), clockwise: false)

UIColor.white.fill()
UIRectFill(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
// Drawing the background with a clipping
UIGraphicsPushContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
UIColor(...).setFill()
UIRectClip(CGRect(x: 0.0, y:10.0 + 180.0 * (1.0 - percentage), width:size.width, height:size.height))
circlePath.fill()
// leave the subcontext to discard the clipping
UIGraphicsPopContext()
UIColor(...).setStroke()
circlePath.lineWidth = 10.0
circlePath.stroke()

// Keep the fruits of our labour
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```